# Quartz.NET - long running jobs?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.NET in a Windows Forms application I have, and I have a long running (5-6 hours) job that runs overnight.

I have an issue now though, where the Quartz scheduler seems to 'timeout', because after the job is executed, scheduled jobs do not run and I cannot interact with Quartz in anyway until I close and reopen my application.

I know an option is splitting the job up into multiple parts, but this is not really ideal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone wondering, the issue was not with Quartz - something I was doing in a Job Listener was causing an error.

Comment: Could you tell what was the problem and the solution?